# how to adapt my code to magento 1?

Tags: magento-1.9

I made a code to get all the bundle products that a normal product belongs to and I made all the logic in a single phtml file. But I want to organize the best way. Where should I put this code? I'm on magento 1.

```
 $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

        $query = "SELECT DISTINCT catalog_product_bundle_selection.parent_product_id FROM catalog_product_bundle_selection INNER JOIN catalog_product_bundle_option_value ON (catalog_product_bundle_option_value.option_id = catalog_product_bundle_selection.option_id) WHERE catalog_product_bundle_option_value.title = '$productSku'";

        $query_result = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a Model class. Add all code related to DB in it.

   ```
    class Vendor_Module_Model_Myclass extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract{

      public function _construct()

      {
          parent::_construct();
      }

      public function getCustomData($optionalParam=array())
      {
          //DB operations here
          return $desiredData;
      }
    }
   ```
2. Create Block class and call Model class functions in it.

   ```
    class Vendor_Module_Block_Myblock extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
    {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getCustomData()
    {
        return Mage::getModel('module/myclass')->getCustomData();
    }
    }
   ```
3. Call block function in phtml file.

   ```
    $this->getCustomData();
   ```